# Validar input dinamico vanilla js

Tags: javascript

Cabe señalar que, la cantidad de la segunda pestaña con input precio se crea dinámicamente al agregar desde la primera pestaña.

1 Al momento de agregar un elemento de la primera pestaña y si se presiona el botón guardar debe mandarse una alerta "hay 2 campos vacíos".

2 El botón guardar debe estar deshabilitado, hasta que se agregue un elemento de la tabs-one. Cuando se agregue un elemento a la tabs-two recién hay habilitar el botón y al click de este elemento, debe de saltar un alert "hay 3 campos vacíos"
recién llenado todos los inputs debe de ejecutarse lo que se necesita hacer por ahora que diga al click del botón mandar un alert con el siguiente mensaje "campos llenos"

3 Al agregar un elemento en la tabla de la pestaña dos,al click del botón debería de decir que hay 3 campos vacíos y si se agrega otro elemento, debería incrementarse, diciendo "hay 4 campos vacíos" y asi sucesivamente si es que se agregan mas elementos a la segunda tabla

4 en  el botón, si escribe en algún input vacío, esta cantidad debe disminuir y cada vez que presiona el botón guardar, debería de decir "hay n inputs vacíos".
al presionar el botón guardar también al click debe de colocarse el foco al primer inputs vacío

```js
const id_prod = document.querySelector('#first-tab >#articulos>#productos_content>.tr >.id_n').textContent;
console.log(id_prod)

const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.querySelector('#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidadNuevo(input);
  
console.log(id,input);
}



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')
console.log(addToShoppingCartButtons)
addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
  
  
  
  
  
  function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;

  
  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,  cantidad_disponible, talla);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,cantidad_disponible,talla) {
    

  if(cantidad_disponible!=0){
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
     
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);

  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

   



    
    
    <td class="table__cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" type="number"
                    value="1" min="1">
                
                </td>
         <td class="table__precio">
     <input required id="precio_${id_prod}" type="text" class="precio"   onchange="CarritoTotalmio()" min="0">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__delete">
     <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>
     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
}else{
  console.log("tiene un 0 imposible agregar");
}
}


})


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const form = document.getElementById("form2");
            const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");
            const botonGuardar = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

            form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Aquí puedes realizar las acciones necesarias al enviar el formulario
            });

            inputs.forEach((input) => {
                input.addEventListener("input", validarFormulario);
            });

            validarFormulario();

            function validarFormulario() {
                let camposVacios = 0;

                inputs.forEach((input) => {
                    if (input.value.trim() === "") {
                        camposVacios++;
                    }
                });

                if (camposVacios > 0) {
                    botonGuardar.disabled = true;
                    botonGuardar.value = `Hay ${camposVacios} campos vacíos`;
                } else {
                    botonGuardar.disabled = false;
                    botonGuardar.value = "Guardar";
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
            <td class="talla"> 36</td>
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
  
        </tr> 
       
       <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">1<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 7</td>
            <td class="talla"> 40</td>
          
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(1)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
    
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    
          </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
      <form id="form2" >
<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo"class="form-control" required>
                
                    <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar"  />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
 
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>   
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>          
            <TH>cantidad </TH>
            <TH>precio </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>


</html>
```

funciona a medias si agrego 5 veces el 4to queda null, es lo mas proximo a input dinamico

```js
var counter = 0;
function addInput(divName){
counter++; 
var Ai8ousa = document.createElement('div'); 
 Ai8ousa.innerHTML = "Field: "+(counter +1) + "<input type='text' name='field[]'>";   
document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(Ai8ousa);

}

function validations(form){
var field;
var i=0;
do{
     field=form[i];
       if (field.value=='')
          {
            alert('The field is null!!!');
            return false;
          }
        i++;
}while(i<counter);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validations(this)" >
<div id="dynamicInput">
Field : <input type="text" name="field[]" />  <br />
</div>
<input type="button" value="New field" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```